# Is there a classification for words combined with hyphens used as adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, dashes

Is there a term or classification for words (non-adjectives, for lack of a better classifier) that are combined with hyphens that serve the purpose of an adjective? For example, "**run-of-the-mill** applicant" or "**less-than-ideal** scenario." Are there any specific rules that dictate how these word groupings are handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called compound adjectives. You will find an overview with some rules and examples on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Compound_adjectives). Note that you should normally use [hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) ( - ), not [dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) ( – or — ) in compound adjectives.

Comment: Thanks for the direction and clarification. I feel terrible for having not known this already!

Comment: @LucasTizma: Nah, don't worry: it is only a label and a convention.